# 33/31/32 frames skipped, although i'm using runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android

My imageview animation skips frames although i am using runOnUiThread. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Here's my java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView a;
TranslateAnimation pengesat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    pengesat = new TranslateAnimation( 0.0f,  300.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f );
    pengesat.setDuration(5000);
    pengesat.setRepeatCount(2);
    pengesat.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      a.startAnimation(pengesat);
                  }
              });
        }
    }).start();
    }
   }
```

And here's my xml code. I am only using four imageViews, may the Images' sizes be too large? I have seen many tutorials and i think i am using threads right, but why does the frames skip, and why does it say that the main thread may be doing too much work??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@string/layout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ennio.lojaprove.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/border"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/border"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/pengesa"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I always hate saying (especially when I just provided an answer) this but when you have a question on stackoverflow that ended up having a right answer, you should mark it as accepted. Upvoting and marking as accepted are two different things. If anyone were to come see a previous question of yours that has multiple different answers that person may not know what ended up being right and helping you. Additionally, it lets the different users providing answers know whether or not they were able to give you the right direction.

Comment: I'm not saying this particularly about this question but I see in your question history you have not marked a single answer as accepted. You should go back through and do that :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm new to stackoverflow and i don't know how to use it properly. but i'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: No problem! I thought I would let you know now so that in the future you can become a better member of the SO community :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're skipping frames it's likely because the main thread is doing too much work. The other possibility is that you're blocking the main thread in some way (waiting on async call, sleep, etc). In this case, however, from your code I would suspect it's because it's doing too much work.

A bigger problem I see, though, is that you shouldn't be spawning a thread here.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  a.startAnimation(pengesat);
              }
          });
    }
}).start();
```

What this does is create a separate thread that lives very briefly. All it does in this short time is add a runnable to be executed on the main thread.

You should replace the above code with the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        a.startAnimation(pengesat);
    }
});
```

---

In the case of seeing skipped frames on the android emulator, you probably don't have to worry unless the number is greater than 60 or so. The android emulator is extremely slow and I would not be surprised to see skipped frames on it especially when doing animations. You can safely ignore this message (in this case).

---

Supposedly, if you're still getting this message on a real device, this might be a potential solution:

```
a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
pengesat = new TranslateAnimation( 0.0f,  300.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f );
pengesat.setDuration(5000);
pengesat.setRepeatCount(2);
pengesat.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
a.setAnimation(pengesat); //<-- this line here is new
```

I've read somewhere that on android 4.2.2 you have to set the animation being used on the view *before* calling `startAnimation`. I have never tried this myself but might extend to 5.0+ android

Comment: I did replace but i still get the same message, "Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on it's main thread", :/

Comment: @Eani the replacement wasn't there to fix this skipped xx frames issue. This was a general code issue i was merely pointing out. Is this on a real phone or an emulator?

Comment: Oh ok, it's on an emulator, may be because of this?

Comment: @Eani absolutely. The emulator is extremely slow. If you did this on a real device I would almost guarantee you wouldn't see this message (for the code in your question). Additionally, seeing the app skip frames is generally not good but it's negligible if it's small like 30 or so. If the app starts to skip 60-70 or more frames then there's definitely a real problem there. You should be good. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: I tried that on a real device, it still skips frames. I don't understand, why does it say that the application may be doing too much work on it's main thread, when i am doing the animation in another thread? Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Eani you should **not** be doing the animation in another thread. In fact, you **can't** do it in another thread. `runOnUIThread` quite literally takes the runnable and puts it in queue to be run on the main thread when the system can get to it. Do you notice visible latency on a real device? What device was it?

Comment: No there's no visible latency, it's a motorola, 5.0.1 API 22.

Comment: @Eani I added an edit with something you can try. Tell me if this works.

Comment: No, still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100183/discussion-between-iismathwizard-and-eani).